# Where does `/dev/pts/ptmx` come from?

Tags: linux, pty

On my Archlinux, `/dev/pts` is mounted by the devpts, so who created the  `/dev/pts/ptmx` device node? What's the purpose of this node?  it's the same (Major=5 Minor=2) device node same as `/dev/ptmx/`, but with different access mode, for what?

Comment: "who created `/dev/pts/ptmx`?" devpts, of course. `# mkdir /tmp/pts; mount -t devpts pts /tmp/pts; ls -l /tmp/pts`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The old AT&T System 5 mechanism for pseudo-terminal slave devices was that they were ordinary *persistent* character device nodes under `/dev`.  There was a multiplexor *master* device at `/dev/ptmx`.  The old 4.3BSD mechanism for pseudo-terminal devices had parallel pairs of ordinary *persistent* master and slave device nodes under `/dev`.  These were special device nodes on an ordinary disc filesystem.

On OpenBSD, some of this is still true nowadays.  `/dev` is still a disc volume, and slave devices are still real on-disc nodes.  They are created on demand, however.  The kernel internally issues the relevant calls to create new device nodes there when issued a `PTMGET` I/O control on the `/dev/ptm` device.

On FreeBSD, none of this is still true.  There isn't even a multiplexor device any more.  `/dev` is not a disc volume at all.  It is a `devfs` filesystem.  Slave devices appear in the `devfs` filesystem under its `pts/` directory in response to the `posix_openpt()` system call, which is an outright system call, not a wrapped `ioctl()` on an open file descriptor to some "multiplexor" evice.

For a while on Linux, pseudo-terminal slave devices were persistent device nodes.  What you are looking at is its "new" `devpts` filesystem (where "new" means introduced quite a few years ago, now) in conjunction with `devtmpfs`.  This *almost* permits the same way of doing things as on FreeBSD with `devfs`.

But there are some differences.  In particular, there is still a "multiplexor" device.

- In the *older* "new" `devpts` system, this was a `ptmx` device in a different `devtmpfs` filesystem, with the `devpts` filesystem containing only the automatically created/destroyed slave device files.  Conventionally the setup was `/dev/ptmx` and an accompanying `devpts` mount at `/dev/pts`.
- But Linux people wanted to have *multiple wholly independent* instances of the `devpts` filesystem, for containers and the like, and it turned out to be quite hard synchronizing the (correct) two filesystems when there were *many* `devtmpfs` and `devpts` filesystems.  So in the *newer* "new" `devpts` system all of the devices, multiplexor and slave, are in the one filesystem.

  For backwards compatibility, the default was for the new `ptmx` node to be inaccessible unless one set a new `ptmxmode` mount option.  In backwards compatibility mode one could still run things the older single-instance way, and one did by default unless one used an explicit `newinstance` option when mounting a `devpts`.
- In the *even newer still* "new" `devpts` (that has been around since 2016) the per-instance multiplexor device in the `devpts` filesystem is now the primary multiplexor, and the `ptmx` in the `devtmpfs` is a shim provided by the kernel that tries to mimic a symbolic link, a bind mount, or a plain old *actual* symbolic link to `pts/ptmx`.  The multiple-instance way is now the *only* way.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470853/5132
- [What would be the best way to work around this glibc problem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68164/)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/214685/5132
- `Documentation/filesystems/devpts.txt`.  Linux kernel.
- Daniel Berrange (2009-05-20). *[`/dev/pts` must use the 'newinstance' mount flag to avoid security problem with containers](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=501718)*.  Red Hat bug #501718.
- Eric W. Biederman (2015-12-11).
  *[devpts: Sensible /dev/ptmx & force newinstance](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/12/11/876)*. Linux kernel mailing list.
- Eric W. Biederman (2016-04-08).
  *[devpts: Teach /dev/ptmx to find the associated devpts via path lookup](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/4/8/484)*. Linux kernel mailing list.